# A sequence $(S_n)$ of reals where Lim inf $(S_n) = -\infty$ and lim sup $(S_n) = +\inf$ and $(S_n)$ is a convergent sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am struggling finding an example of this. A sequence $(S_n)$ of reals where Lim inf $(S_n) = -\infty$ and lim sup $(S_n) = +\infty$ and $(S_n)$ is a convergent sequence

Comment: if limit exists lim=liminf=limsup

Comment: Do you know the definition of a convergent sequence or of limsup or of liminf?

Answer (score 2):

if a sequence converges, then its limit is equal to the lim sup and the lim inf. Thus what you are looking for does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to prove a false statement. To say that $S_{n}$ converges to a number $L$ means exactly that $\lim\inf S_{n}=\lim\sup S_{n}=L$. So no subsequence can go to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.

However, if you replace "sequence" with "series," the statement becomes true. You can have a sequence $S_{n}$ s.t. $\sum S_{n}$ converges but $\exists$ subsequences $S_{n_{i}}$ and $S_{n_{s}}$ s.t. $\sum S_{n_{i}}=-\infty$ and $\sum S_{n_{s}}=+\infty$.